# Ajax.dll causing problem?

Tags: .net, ajax

I am using `Ajax.dll`.I have registered the class using

`Ajax.Utility.RegisterTypeForAjax(typeof(Default))` in page load.

I have written a function in the server side to return "Name",like

```
[Ajax.AjaxMethod(HttpSessionStateRequirement.ReadWrite)]
public string GetName()
{
return "Test";
}
```

and i accessed from the page like 
`Default.GetName()`.

For first time its working fine.after leaving system idle for one hour if click any link, that throws error "default is undefined ".

Is there anyway to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Check your local system configuration & development server, whether that are same?

Copy all dll into your bin folder, it some references are missing out

Give namespace to web page

Comment: My application is web site.If its a web application, we can set namespace.

All of my dlls are in bin folder only.